# How is Visual Studio 2022 exploring/parsing .playlist files?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2022, xunit, trx

I've been working on a .trx to .playlist parser that discovers all failed tests in a xUnit test result from a nightly build and puts them into a .playlist file so that those can be run in Visual Studio without having to hand pick the failed ones from a list of 5k unit tests.

So far with quite some success, the .playlist file is validly created and most tests show up in the playlist window. Some tests though do not show up, because for whatever reason, VS is or was expecting a different format.

Instead of the `FullNamespace.Class.Method(arguments)` style in the innermost `Property` tags that worked for all other Tests, now it just expected `Method(arguments)`. I found this out by manually adding the same test to the playlist in Visual Studio, which it added to the same `Class` tag, but without the fully qualified name.

Just to test, I moved the file into a new folder that represented its namespace (it was located directly under the project) and suddenly VS shifted the format to the fully qualified one. So I thought that it looks at the folder structure within a project in order to discover tests from a .playlist file, but after then moving the file back to its original spot (I can't just move files around in a massive project) VS would **STILL** use the fully qualified format to write the test into the playlist file.

So... does anyone one know what the conditions are for a test in a .playlist file to show up in the playlist window?